# Making ion slides slide vertically

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have `start.html` file having options property having of the  and I will define them in options1 in class StartPage

```
<ion-slide [options]="option1" *ngFor="let slide of slides; let last = last">
  <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image"/>
  <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="slide.title" style=""></h2>
  <p [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>

  <div id="skip-b">
    <button (click)="dismiss()">
      {{last ? "Let's Begin" : "Skip" }}
      <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```

start.ts:

```
export class StartPage {
    option1 = {
        loop: true,
        direction: 'vertical'
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the options in the `ion-slides` component as shown in their [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/).

```
<ion-slides [options]="option1">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let last = last">
        <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image" />
        <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="slide.title" style=""></h2>
        <p [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>

        <div id="skip-b">
            <button (click)="dismiss()">
      {{last ? "Let's Begin" : "Skip" }}
      <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
    </button>
        </div>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of ionic we can easily achieve vertical scroll by passing `[options]` value to `<ion-slides>`.

Here is an example.

```
// page.ts
export class SlideClass {
  slideOptions = {
    direction: 'vertical',
  };
  constructor(){}
 
}

// html file
<ion-slides [options]="slideOptions">
```

More option we can found here [more slide options](https://swiperjs.com/api/)

Answer (score 0):

you can make your slides vertical by adding ''direction'' parameter.

```
<ion-slides direction="vertical">

</ion-slides>
```

by default slides are horizontal.